# How can i show web page in a modal using react native WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-modal

i want to show the web page in a modal, I am using this line of code but it is showing me blank modal.

```
<WebView source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}/>
```

Comment: Wheres the code for your modal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have provided more from code then it could help to fix the bug on your code self. However format of the code should be right below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Modal, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class TestClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showModal : false
        }
    }



    ActivityIndicatorLoadingView() {
       return (
         <ActivityIndicator
            color="#009688"
            size="large"
            style={styles.ActivityIndicatorStyle}
         /> 
       );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex : 1, justifyContent : 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Button title="Press" onPress={() => this.setState({showModal : !this.state.showModal})}/>
                <Modal  visible={this.state.showModal}>
                    <View style={styles.modal}>
                        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <WebView 
                                style={{ flex : 1 }} 
                                source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}/>
                                renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modal : {
        flex : 1,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    },
    modalContainer : {
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        width : '90%',
        height : '90%',
    },
    ActivityIndicatorStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
})
export default TestClass
```

Comment: this is working well but i am unable to go back or cancel even using phone back button and when i reload the app it is not reloading. can you give me a solution for that.

Comment: How do you want to go back? is it to be canceled the Modal when press back button or going back in the webview?

Comment: ok done i remove the modal, can i add a loader before loading the page in modal

Comment: Okay now have a look. You could use BackHandler with hardwareBackPress event as well to close your modal when press back button.

Answer (score 3):

I developed nice package for this. If you want you can examine or use it. The link of the package is https://github.com/ilkerkesici/react-native-beauty-webview.